# Select from list where not appear in second list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a quite strange issue that is hard to explain:

I've got 2 lists, one of them contains object: Car (**id**,make,model) and second list of "Reservations" that contain (id,datefrom,dateto,**carid**). Now I need to linq select all the items from first list, that doesn't appear on the second list.

I have no idea how to linq where to specific object of another list:

```
var emptyCars = cars.Where(c => c.id != /*element of reservationlist.carid*/)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var emptyCars = cars.Where(c => !reservation.Any(y=> y.carID == c.ID));
```

You can use [**Enumerable.Any**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

Comment: thanks! as soon as I will be able to accept it, I'll do for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Try rearranging your linq statement:

`var emptyCars = cars.Where(c => !reservation.Any(r => r.carid == c.id));`

Comment: car.id should be c.id